# MongoDB text searching across fields

Tags: mongodb, search, text

In am using

```
db.version()
4.0.0
```

I have the following collection,

```
db.items.find( {}, {name:1, description: 1, _id: 0} );

{ "name" : "test", "description" : "this is a test" }
{ "name" : "foo", "description" : "this is another test" }
{ "name" : "test2", "description" : "this is something" }
{ "name" : "bar", "description" : "this is something" }
```

I make sure there is a text index on 2 fields via,

```
db.items.ensureIndex({name:"text", description: "text"});
```

The output is,

```
{
    "createdCollectionAutomatically" : false,
    "numIndexesBefore" : 2,
    "numIndexesAfter" : 2,
    "note" : "all indexes already exist",
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Running this,

```
db.items.find({$text: {$search: "something" }}, {_id:0});
```

shows

```
{ "name" : "bar", "description" : "this is something" }
{ "name" : "test2", "description" : "this is something" }
```

Running this,

```
db.items.find({$text: {$search: "bar" }}, {_id:0});
```

shows

```
{ "name" : "bar", "description" : "this is something" }
```

But, running this,

```
db.items.find({$text: {$search: "is" }}, {_id:0});
```

shows nothing. Why would this be the case???

Reindexing no affect,

```
db.items.reindex()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word 'is' is being ignored because it is a 'stop word' in the English language.

> MongoDB supports text search for various languages. Text indexes drop
>   language-specificstop words (e.g. in English, the, an, a, and,
>   etc.) and use simple language-specific suffix stemming.

(https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/#supported-languages-and-stop-words)

Note that the default language associated with text indexes is [English](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/specify-language-for-text-index/#specify-the-default-language-for-a-text-index).

Specifying a `default_language` of `none` will use simple tokenization with [no list of stop words and no stemming.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/text-search-languages/#text-search-languages)

For example:

```
> db.items.ensureIndex({ "name" : "text", "description" : "text" }, { "default_language" : "none" } )
{
    "createdCollectionAutomatically" : false,
    "numIndexesBefore" : 1,
    "numIndexesAfter" : 2,
    "ok" : 1
}
> db.items.find({$text: {$search: "is" }}, {_id:0});
{ "name" : "bar", "description" : "this is something" }
{ "name" : "test2", "description" : "this is something" }
{ "name" : "foo", "description" : "this is another test" }
{ "name" : "foo", "description" : "this is another test" }
{ "name" : "test", "description" : "this is a test" }
```

Comment: OMG. THANK YOU very much. I did not come upon that nuance in reviewing the various document web pages.